# Move newsletter from products page to home page?

Tags: magento

I installed magento with sample data. If I click on "furniture" for example, newsletter shows at the bottom of the left columnt, below tags. On the homepage, tags are there but no newsletter.

How would I put newsletter there as well?

I tried just pasting the php code there but it just showed the form but the form didn't work.

I am guessing I should edit the xml somehow, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a one column layout, and was able to call this via:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

I don't know what version you are on, but that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think sample magento home page handle by admin

goto->admin->cms->pages->Home page->content (left side)->add below code after tag block

{{block type="tag/popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"}}

{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}